# ElasticSearch NEST - Use UpdateByQuery to create a non existing field or update an existing one

Tags: elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch-6, elasticsearch-query

I'm pretty new to elasticsearch (6.6.0), i'd like to achieve a single query that can both create/update a document based on a custom field.

Here is my document structure

```
{
    "_index" : "document",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "nvs9gmkB0wioRAGjGGVA",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_source" : {
      "customId" : "4a3e7b21-9be9-4378-98ec-aa3e9f40aee7",
      "title" : "test",
    }
}
```

Using NEST (Last known nuget package) i built the following method to add/update a field in the document

```
var response = await _client.UpdateByQueryAsync < dynamic > (s => s
 .Index("document")
 .Type("_doc")
 .Query(q => q.Match(t => t
  .Field("customId")
  .Query("4a3e7b21-9be9-4378-98ec-aa3e9f40aee7")
 ))
 .Script(sc => sc
  .Source("ctx._source." + PARAMETER_NAME + " = params." + PARAMETER_NAME)
  .Params(p => p
   .Add(PARAMETER_NAME, PARAMETER_VALUE)
  )
  .Lang(ScriptLang.Painless)
 )
 .RequestsPerSecond(-1)
 .WaitForCompletion()
 .Refresh()
).ConfigureAwait(false);

if (!response.IsValid) {
 //error logic goes here
}

return response;
```

If i try to use the method to **UPDATE** the title of the document with the given customId everything works out just fine.
However if I try to use the same method to **ADD** a field to the document **nothing happens**, the query returns a "valid nest response built from a successful low level call on post" and moves on.

I've tried to replicate the same query and execute it on kibana and it works just fine, updating the document, here's the query :

```
POST document/_doc/_update_by_query?requests_per_second=-1&wait_for_completion=true&refresh=true
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "customId": {
        "query": "4a3e7b21-9be9-4378-98ec-aa3e9f40aee7"
      }
    }
  },
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "datetime": "2019-03-15T11:44:43.555Z"
    },
    "source": "ctx._source.datetime = params.datetime"
  }
}
```

At this point i'm pretty lost, what am i missing?

Thank you.

**P.S** : The document is likely to change over time, to deal with that i've created a template for all my documents, once created the document index has the following dynamic template :

```
"dynamic_templates" : [
          {
            "string_fields" : {
              "match" : "*",
              "path_unmatch" : "customId",
              "match_mapping_type" : "string",
              "mapping" : {
                "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
                "search_analyzer" : "autocomplete_search",
                "type" : "text"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
```

Comment: Why not just reindex all documents with the proper mapping? Otherwise, searching for the datetime property would not find anything, as the datatype is not known.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the document is likely to change over time, adding new parameters i can't map right away, to deal with that i've created an Index Template that maps all the Text kinda field and makes them searchable using a custom Analyzer and SearchAnalyzer. I've already tried, via kibana, updating a document with a new Text parameter and, as expected, the parameter is searchable right away thanks to the analyzers. **Updated my question**

Comment: Is `customId` a unique identifier for a document? If so, have you considered using it as the `_id` for the document in Elasticsearch?

Comment: Yes, I've noticed I can use the customId as the document _id, as such I've changed the updatebyquery to a standard update with upsert and it's now working. Thanks @RussCam for getting me to notice it!